# No last post information about any other user, in Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, session, authentication, socket.io

I request your support ...
I have the following structure hyper summary:

```
variable1 = "username bd successfully extracted in Mysql, here there is no problem, and I checked"

io.sockets.on ('connection', function (socket) {
socket.emit ('initialize', {username: variable1}
}
```

As you will understand I have several users connecting and if for example I have 5 that connect one after the other, if all (CONNECTED) update the browser, all automatically inherit the name of the last user which obviously do not want to, and everyone should have its own name. I tried to fix it by implementing sessions, but does not allow me to use them within io.sockets.on ('connection', function (socket)).

I hope anyone could fix this problem before, I thank you once again for your invaluable help.

---

No. I make the connection out. To understand me better, I'll post my code, maybe you can help me (and forgive me if I caused any discomfort). My language is Spanish, but use Google Translate to help me explain my problem, hopefully not confusing. In Spanish, there is not much information, I have recommended the use of passport.js, but I'm a beginner and do not know how to implement it, what to remove, should be removed to work ... would solicit help please. Thank you very much!

My code is:

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , user = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , mysql = require('mysql');

var crypto = require('crypto');

var app = express();
server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(port);


/*http.createServer(app).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + 3000);
});*/

app.configure(function(){
  /*app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);*/
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.session({secret: 'esto es secreto'}));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});



var db_config = {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'user',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'db_name'
};

var coneccion;

function handleDisconnect() {
  coneccion = mysql.createConnection(db_config);    // Recreate the connection, since
                                                                    // the old one cannot be reused.

  coneccion.connect(function(err) {                 // The server is either down
    if(err) {                                                   // or restarting (takes a while sometimes).
      console.log('error when connecting to db:', err);
      setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000);               // We introduce a delay before attempting to reconnect,
    }                                                               // to avoid a hot loop, and to allow our node script to
  });                                               // process asynchronous requests in the meantime.
                                                                    // If you're also serving http, display a 503 error.
    coneccion.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('db error', err);
        if(err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {   // Connection to the MySQL server is usually
            handleDisconnect();                                 // lost due to either server restart, or a
        } else {                                                        // connnection idle timeout (the wait_timeout
            throw err;                                              // server variable configures this)
        }
    });
}

handleDisconnect();


function login(req, res, next){
  if(req.session.user){
    next();
  }else{
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
}

function encriptar(cadena){
  var myString = cadena;
  return crypto.createHash('md5').update(myString).digest("hex");
}

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);

// pagina que renderiza el formulario del login.
app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', {title: 'Ingreso'});
});

app.get('/principal', login, function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/pantalla_principal.html');
});

app.get('/profesor', login, function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/pantalla_profesor.html');
});

app.post('/autenticar', function(req, res){
  //var connection = BD();
  var user = req.body.txtUsuario;
  var clave = encriptar(req.body.txtClave);
  coneccion.query('SELECT * FROM sm_usuario WHERE nombre="'+ user +'" and contrasena="'+ clave +'"' , function(error, resultado, fila){
    if(!error){
      if(resultado.length>0){
        console.log("EL ID DEL USUARIO ES: "+ resultado[0].id_usuario);
        coneccion.query('SELECT * FROM sm_alumno WHERE id_usuario="'+ resultado[0].id_usuario +'"', function(error, resultado2, fila2){
          if(!error){
              req.session.user        = user;
              nivel_acceso            = resultado[0].nivel_acceso;
              avatar                  = resultado[0].id_avatar;
              id_usuario              = resultado[0].id_usuario;

              nombre_completo   = resultado2[0].nombre;

              id_grado          = resultado2[0].id_grado;
              id_colegio        = resultado2[0].id_colegio;
              id_ubigeo         = resultado2[0].id_ubigeo;
              coneccion.query('SELECT c1 FROM sm_colegio WHERE id="'+ resultado2[0].id_colegio +'"', function(error, resultado3, fila3){
                if(!error){
                  colegio = resultado3[0].c1;
                  // averiguamos en qué departamento esta el alumno
                  coneccion.query('SELECT * FROM ubigeo WHERE id="'+ resultado2[0].id_ubigeo +'"', function(error, resultado4, fila4){
                    if(!error){
                      departamento = resultado4[0].dep;
                      id_dep = resultado4[0].iddep;
                      id_pro = resultado4[0].idpro;
                      id_dis = resultado4[0].iddis;
                      if(nivel_acceso=="1"){
                        res.redirect('/principal');
                      }else if(nivel_acceso=="2"){
                        res.redirect('/profesor');
                      }
                    }else{
                      res.send("La información sobre el usuario no está completa - 3");
                      //res.send(error);
                    }
                  })
                }else{
                  //res.send(error);
                            res.send("La información sobre el usuario no está completa - 2");
                }
              })
          }else{
            //res.send(error)
            //res.send("La información sobre el usuario no está completa");
            console.log("La información sobre el usuario no está completa");
          }
        });
      }else{
        //res.send("El usuario no existe o sus datos son incorrectos");
        console.log("El usuario no existe o sus datos son incorrectos");
      }
    }else{
      console.log("Ocurrio un error: "+ error);
    }
  });
});

app.get('/salir', function(req, res){
  delete req.session.user;
  res.redirect('/');
});

conectados = new Array();

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  var tot = conectados.length;
  conectados[tot] = {
      "nombre": nombre_completo, 
      "colegio": colegio, 
      "id_usuario": id_usuario, 
      "id_colegio": id_colegio, 
      "id_grado": id_grado, 
      "id_dep": id_dep, 
      "id_pro":id_pro, 
      "id_dis": id_dis, 
      "departamento": departamento
    }
  socket.emit('inicializar', {id_usuario: id_usuario, id_colegio: id_colegio, id_grado: id_grado, nombre_completo: nombre_completo, colegio: colegio, id_avatar: avatar, departamento: departamento, id_dep: id_dep, id_pro: id_pro, id_dis: id_dis, nivel_acceso: nivel_acceso});
  socket.broadcast.emit('lista_chat_completa', {"usuarios_chat": conectados })
  socket.emit('lista_chat_personal', {"usuarios_chat": conectados })

  socket.on('mensaje_chat_cliente', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('mensaje_chat_servidor', { "nombre": data.nombre, "colegio": data.colegio, "departamento": data.departamento, "mensaje": data.mensaje, "fecha": data.fecha, "hora": data.hora });
  });

  socket.on('nuevo_post_cliente', function (data){
    socket.broadcast.emit('nuevo_post_servidor', { id_dep: data.id_dep, id_pro: data.id_pro, id_dis: data.id_dis, id_grado: data.id_grado, id_avatar: data.id_avatar, comunidad: data.comunidad, id_colegio: data.id_colegio, id_titulo: data.id_titulo, id_usuario: data.id_usuario, nombre_completo: data.nombre_completo, colegio: data.colegio, departamento: data.departamento, texto: data.texto, id_post: data.id_post, fecha: data.fecha, hora: data.hora });
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    for(i=0; i<conectados.length; i++){
      if(conectados[i].id_usuario==id_usuario){
        conectados.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    for(i=0; i<conectados.length; i++){
      console.log("Nombre: "+ conectados[i].nombre + " Colegio: " + conectados[i].colegio)
    }
    socket.broadcast.emit('lista_chat_completa', {"usuarios_chat": conectados })
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your database call is asynchronous. Is your DB call inside the connection event? If not, what you return may not be what you want.

You should have something like:

```
io.sockets.on ('connection', function (socket) {
  mysql.find($query, function(err, variable1) {  // This anonymous function is a callback.
    socket.emit('initialize', { username: variable1 });
  };
});
```